# Primary Key - VARBINARY or BLOB or VARCHAR for UUID primary key

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, blob, varbinary

I am using UUID as the primary key in one of the tables.
What are the pros-cons of having this field as a varchar/varbinary/blob?

Comment: In fact, are you sure you want to use UUID as the primary key? If you are using InnoDB, it is a poor choice for performance due to the nature of clustered index.

Comment: Yes, UUID is the way to go for this table.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between text-based and binary-based UUID is a significant number of bytes - 16 for binary representation vs. 30+ for text - so binary is the way to go.  I would opt for VARBINARY over BLOB - if only 'cause VARBINARY is the newer type (and coming from a SQL Server background, I know VARBINARY *there* can be stored in-row).

Comment: I agree, would not use a blob.

Comment: is there a difference in performance when using varchar and varbinay?

Comment: The size of the UUIDs in binary format will always take 16 bytes, so it's better to use `BINARY(16)` than `VARBINARY(16)`.